# live cd installation

Tags: livedvd

I downloaded ubuntu-12.04.4-dvd-i386.iso from Ubuntu website, and I burn an image on a dvd.
now when I insert the dvd and restart my computer and booted it from the dvd I got a massage said: bootmngr missing press ctrl+alt+del to restart.
pleas any help.

Comment: Did you set the correct boot order in your BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu DVD image you have downloaded must be corrupted. Please verify the MD5 or SHA checksum signature of the image you have downloaded.